# The total size of 32-bit memory address, 32-bit data words memory arrays?

Tags: digital-logic, memory

[image]

I see that the total size of 32Kb = 32 x 1Kb.

> The ARM architecture uses 32-bit memory addresses and 32-bit data words.

This means, the ARM memory array depth-width is 2^32 words and 32-bit, which is 32 x 23Kb = 736Kb in total size?

Comment: Didn't understand. What is 23?

Comment: 2^10 = 1Kb, so 2^11 = 2Kb, 2^12 = 3Kb and so on

Comment: The fact, that addres bus is 32bit wide, doesn't mean that memory has depth of 2^32 - it can be smaller

Comment: You sure your math is right? it should go like 1, 2, 4 .....

Comment: 2^12 is 4k, not 3k.

Comment: note that memories are often specified in bits not bytes (not packaged modules, but the actual chips)(flash, dram, etc).  1024 x 32 = 32768 bits or 32Kb(its).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ARM architecture, byte-addressing is used. ie., each address location can address a byte.

With 32-bit address bus and byte-addressable scheme, \$2^{32}\$ addressing locations are possible at maximum, and each address location can address a byte.

So the **total addressable memory** in such a system will be \$2^{32}\$ bytes or 4 GB.
This doesn't always mean that you have a big memory array of 4GB in your architecture.

For instance, the 4 GB address space may be shared by different peripherals and their addressing space, and a memory array.

In your example, the memory array in the ARM architecture is [1024-word x 32-bit array]. It has 10-bit address line (which should be derived from 32-bit address bus), and 32-bit data line. It means it can store \$2^{10}=1024\$ [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)), where each word means 32-bits. So it's correct in your textbook that its a 32 Kb memory array.